# It's a function or table in this later join case?

Tags: postgresql

It is often particularly handy to LEFT JOIN to a LATERAL subquery, so that source rows will appear in the result even if the LATERAL subquery produces no rows for them. For example, if get_product_names() returns the names of products made by a manufacturer, but some manufacturers in our table currently produce no products, we could find out which ones those are like this:

```
SELECT m.name
FROM manufacturers m LEFT JOIN LATERAL get_product_names(m.id) pname ON true
WHERE pname IS NULL;
```

All contents extract from PostgreSQL manual.  [LINK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html)
Now I finally probably get what does LATERAL mean. In this case,

Overall I am Not sure **get_product_names** is a table or function. The following is my understanding.
A: `get_product_names(m.id)` is a function, and using `m.id` as a input parameter returns a table. The return table alias as `pname`. Overall it's a table m join a null (where condition) table.

B: get_product_names is a table, table m left join table `get_product_names` on `m.id`. `pname` is alias for `get_product_names`. Overall it's a table m join a null (where condition) table.

Answer (score 0):

`get_product_names` is a *table function* (also known as *set returning function* or SRF in PostgreSQL slang). Such a function does not necessarily return a single result row, but arbitrarily many rows.

Since the result of such a function is a table, you typically use it in SQL statements where you would use a table, that is in the `FROM` clause.

A simple example is

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 5);

 generate_series 
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
(5 rows)
```

You can also use normal functions in this way, they are then treated as a table function that returns exactly one row.

Comment: So overall My A guess is correct.  It means that to all the manufacturers name where manufacturers.id is also in pname table.

Comment: No, the way the query is written, it will only return the manufacturer's name. But if there are several product names for one manufacturer, you would get that name as many times as there are products. The query will make more sense if you add a column from `pname` to the `SELECT` list.